# Using Arrays in C (to print an input with another input)

Tags: c, arrays

I tried to make myself clearer on the question but I don't know how to ask my problem.
So I want to create a code in which I input N number of tickets and the N number of winners. Example:

input:

```
5 3 (Here is 5 and a 3, each one a different input)
382
55
44
451
128
1 
4
3
```

Output:

```
382
451
44
```

So what I have of code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int winners;    
    int n;
    int m;
    char ticketWinners[1000][100], ticket[1000];
    int i;
    int j;
    int max[100];

    scanf("%d", &n); //Input for Number of tickets
    scanf("%d", &m); //Input of the ticket numbers(order) that won

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&ticket[i]);
        {
            for(j=0; j<m;j++)   
            {
                scanf("%s", &ticketWinnersj]);  
            }

            if (j=i);
                printf("%d", winners);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I don't know how to print the tickets 1, 4 and 3. (I can choose which tickets that won with the input. So instead of 1, 4 and 3; I can choose 3, 5 and 1 respectively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should work.

In the original code there was a nested loop. I am assuming that this was not the intention.

In the original code the integers were read into a `char` array. I changed it to `int`, because it suits the program logic better.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int winners;
    int n;
    int m;
    int ticketWinners[1000], ticket[1000];
    int i;
    int j;
    int max[100];

    scanf("%d", &n); //Input for Number of tickets
    scanf("%d", &m); //Input of the ticket numbers(order) that won

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ticket[i]);
    }

    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ticketWinners[j]);
    }

    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        // ticketWinners[] has the index of winners. Lets access
        // ticket[] with those indices. Since input index starts 
        // from 1 rather than 0, subtract 1 
        printf("%d \n", ticket[ticketWinners[j] - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your interpretation of the question is correct (it was a bit hard to decipher at first). But a few nits. Why `scanf("%s")` and then `atoi` rather than just `scanf("%d")` directly? And probably should sanitise the input before using it as an index into `ticket` in the last `for` loop.

Comment: You would do well to explain what's different in your solution compared to the original.  (Now you've edited the code, it makes a lot more sense.)  Please note that it is a good idea to ensure that each `scanf()` operation is successful before using the result.

Comment: @kaylum I just fixed it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The original code has nested loops which seems wrong so I removed it. Since they are going to different arrays, I dont see the problem of overwriting

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out, and yes you got the interpretation right (thankfully :) ) but I tried your code and it prints me random ticket numbers. Thanks again.

Comment: @acm1pt2 try now. I missed a `-1`. your indexing starts at 1

Comment: @knightrider: Note that I edited my comment as you edited your answer at about the same time I hit 'add'.  The overwriting problem has gone.  The explanation about what was wrong with the original code and why the revised code is OK is signally missing.  Within limits (minimal error checking, for example), the new code is good, but explaining why is important too.

Comment: @knightrider Thanks a lot. I am really, really grateful. Now I seem to understand. :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I totally agree with checking the whether scanf was successful. I have added some comments. I hope it is clear

Comment: @acm1pt2 Please accept the answer if it fixed your problem